# how to load file one by one with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have many type files such as image, audio, video, word,... I want to load these file one by one. Ex: with image, I want to load next image after finish previous image. How can I do it by jQuery? I try using

```
$('img').load(function () {})
```

I have an array. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var images = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];

function loadImages() {
    if(!images.length)
        return;

    $('<img />', {
        src: images.splice(0, 1),
        onload: loadImages
    }).appendTo('#imgContainer');
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWSrV/)**

This will append each image to `#imgContainer` after the previous in the array loads.

Comment: I do it like in your guide, but it doesn't work, this's my snippet:

<div id="loadImg">
    <img />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
var images = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png', 'img3.png'];

        function loadImages() {
            if (!images.length)
                return;

            $('<img />', {
                src: images.splice(0, 1),
                onload: loadImages
            }).appendTo('#loadImg');
        }
    });
</script>

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle? My solution is a lot more versatile and clean than the one you marked as an answer.

Comment: by the way, can I ask U a question? I want to load base on block. I have 10 images and I want to split it to 2 block, each block include 5 images. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

My implementation for this:

```
var imageInfo = [{
    id : '#img1',
    src : '/images/img1.png'
}, {
    id : '#img2',
    file : '/images/img2.png'
}];
var currentImage = 0;

var loadImage = function(imageNumber) {
    if(imageNumber < imageInfo.length) {
        var img = imageInfo[imageNumber];
        $(img.id).attr('src', img.src);
    };
};
$('img').load(function () {
    loadImage(currentImage ++);
});
loadImage(currentImage);
```

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst yes, assuming there are no other images in the document. If there are you would need to become more specific with the image load callback. i.e. $('img .delayedLoad').load(...);

Answer (score 0):

Faced kind of similar problem, you have to use regular expressions ...

see my question [Display image or swf in same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906570/display-image-or-swf-in-same-tag)

you will get idea what you need to do.